# Using xlwings, how do I print JSON data into multiple columns from multiple URLs?

Tags: python, json, xlwings

I am using grequest to pull json data from multiple urls. Now, I want to print those results to excel using xlwings. Here is the code I have now.

```
import xlwings as xw
import grequests
import json
urls = [
    'https://bittrex.com/api/v1.1/public/getorderbook?market=BTC-1ST&type=both&depth=50',
    'https://bittrex.com/api/v1.1/public/getorderbook?market=BTC-AMP&type=both&depth=50',
    'https://bittrex.com/api/v1.1/public/getorderbook?market=BTC-ARDR&type=both&depth=50',
]

requests = (grequests.get(u) for u in urls)
responses = grequests.map(requests)

for response in responses:
        BQuantity = [response.json()['result']['buy'][0]['Quantity'],
        response.json()['result']['buy'][1]['Quantity'],
        response.json()['result']['buy'][2]['Quantity'],
        response.json()['result']['buy'][3]['Quantity'],
        response.json()['result']['buy'][4]['Quantity']
]
wb = xw.Book('Book2')
sht = wb.sheets['Sheet1']
sht.range('A1:C5').options(transpose=True).value = BQuantity
```

This works just fine, but only if I comment out all but one url, otherwise the results from the first url are overwritten by the results from the second url, an expected result. However, this is not what I want. In the end I want the results from the first URL to dump into column A, the results from the second URL dump into column B, etc...

I am able to pull in each individual link with 'requests' (instead of grequests) one by one, however, this operation is going to consist of a couple hundred urls in which simply pulling the data in one by one is very time consuming. Grequests pulls in 200 urls, and dumps to a JSON file in about 8 seconds compared to normal requests that took about 2 minutes.

Any help would be appreciated.